# Is there a way to reformat w/ zero-fill a regex match group?

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a file with  `9%`,  `22%`,  `100%` and so on.

Is there a Perl (or other) regex way to turn the numbers into "009", `022`, and `100` respectively?

```
perl -p -i -e "s/width: (\d+)%/width_\1/g;" ...
```

correctly returns `width_9`, `width_22`, and `width_100`, which is okay, but if there's a clever, yet simple way to take the `\1` matched group and add in formatting, it would be nice.

Comment: Tip: `\1` is a regex atom (that matches what the first capture matched). It makes no sense to use it in the replacement expression. Use `$1` there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```bash
perl -i -pe 's/width: (\d+)%/sprintf "width_%03s", $1/ge' file
```

Here, `width: (\d+)%` matches `width:` , then captures one or more digits into Group 1 (`$1`, not `\1`!), and a `%` char is also consumed right after, and the match is replaced with `width_` + the reformatted number.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/bgVdna):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='width: 9%, width: 22%, width: 100%'
perl -pe 's/width: (\d+)%/sprintf "width_%03s", $1/ge' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
width_009, width_022, width_100
```

Comment: With `\K`, you can ignore part of the pattern so you don't have to replicate it on the replacement side:  `s/width: \K(\d+)(?=%)/sprintf "%03s", $1/ge'

Comment: bdf means `s/width\K: (\d+)%/sprintf "_%03s", $1/ge`